# Magento Product Export: Use price and image of configurable product for linked simple products

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, export, simple-product

I am trying to find a way to export all my simple products with correct prices and images. For this I would also like to export all simple products linked to configurable ones. Since prices for these linked products are not always up to date, I need to find a way to fetch the configurable products price and use that for all linked simple ones. Same goes for the product image. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to find a way to export all my simple products...

This is possible natively by filtering the on the `type_id` column.

> ... with correct prices and images.

This is confusing. When you export you get the data that you get.

> For this I would also like to export all simple products linked to configurable ones.

This is a subset of the first point, but I think that there is no way to filter on configurable children.

> Since prices for these linked products are not always up to date... Same goes for the product image.

This is only important if you are selling them individually (Visibility for linked products set to either catalog or search or both). You can configure the configurable image to display for the simples (this is the default behavior IIRC).

If it's important to have the simple child data sync'ed, rather than handle this via export I'd recommend to set up an observer and/or a sync job which can keep the data unified within the app. Should not be difficult.